# Famous gypsy/romani physicists?

Tags: physics

Are there any famous/notorious Romani physicist?

Thanks!

Comment: @njuffa All I did was Google search and nothing relevant came up. I am no expert in these endeavours so I don’t know where to dig properly.

Comment: I think, none...

Comment: The wikipedia page [List of notable Romani people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Romani_people) cites [Sofya Kovalevskaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofya_Kovalevskaya) as being one quarter Romani, though her dedicated wikipedia page is less precise, stating only that "There may also have been some Romani ancestry on the father's side."

Comment: @Nick that's something! I find it hard to believe this might be the only case so far, specially accounting modern times.

Comment: IMHO, before speaking of physicists, not to speak of "famous physicists", a fundamental fact is that, till a recent past, Romani people weren't going to school, therefore were only very few to be able to read and write.

Answer (score 0):

My grandmas uncle, but I don't think his Romani ancestry was documented after they came to the U.S. He was considered the top on his field. George Ray Wait.

Comment: Are you referring to George Ray Wait, born September 7, 1886 in Chase, Kansas, died April 9, 1953 in Cambridge Massachusetts? If so, I am puzzled by the remark "after they came to the U.S." I see a few publications by a G. R. Wait from the 1930s and 1940s in the field of terrestrial magnetism, is that the field you are referring to? It would be helpful if some more details could be added to the answer.